# Show that $\min_X \|X\|_2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, singular-values

Given $ A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $\sigma_1$ as biggest singular value, and $\det(I-AX) = 0$ where $ X\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m} $, can you show that
$$\min_X \|X\|_2 = \frac 1{\sigma_1}\:?$$
I believe that $\|X\|_2 \geq \frac1{\sigma_1}$ follows from $1$ being an eigenvalue of $AX$ and the definition of the matrix norm, however I can't show that this bound is attained in all cases. I thought that maybe the pseudo-inverse would give it, but I think that gives the reciprocal of the smallest singular value, not the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\det(I-AX)=0$, there is a $y$ with $\|y\|_2=1$ such that $AXy=y$ so
$$
1=\|y\|_2=\|AXy\|_2\leq \|A\|_2\|X\|_2=\sigma_1\|X\|_2.
$$

Therefore, for any such $X$ (assuming it exists),
$$
\|X\|_2\geq \frac{1}{\sigma_1}.
$$

It remains to show that there is a solution with $\|X\|_2=1/\sigma_1$ (thus solving also the existence problem). Let $u_1$ and $v_1$ be the singular vectors of unit norm corresponding to $\sigma_1$ (such that $Av_1=\sigma_1 u_1$). Let's try to see what happens if we take
$$
X_\star=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}v_1u_1^*.
$$
We certainly have $\|X_\star\|_2=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}$ and
$$
AX_\star=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}Av_1u_1^*=u_1u_1^*.
$$
Now 
$$
(I-AX_\star)u_1=(I-u_1u_1^*)u_1=0,
$$
which shows that $I-AX_\star$ is singular and hence $\det(I-AX_\star)=0$.